# Need to change all values in a pandas column but getting key error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

Update: Looks like I'm getting the KeyError because I did df.rename(columns={'doc_id' : 'UniqueId'}) but this only created an alias name. I need to match the schema of another table for an append operation downstream. Both answers worked if I used 'doc_id'. I suppose I should repost for how to permanently change column names in the dataframe.

I thought this would be straight forward but I'm getting hung up. I have a bunch of unique IDs in brackests and I need to join the data frame with another table using the same IDs that have no brackets; hence I would like to remove the brackets from the target dataframe. The field, or series if you will, is called 'UniqueId'. I have verified this several times.

Initially I tried this:

```
df['UniqueId'].replace(df['UniqueId'], df['UniqueId'][1:-1])
```

Then this:

```
df['UniqueId'].replace('{',)
```

which would have been followed by:

```
df['UniqueId'].replace('}',)
```

either way I get a key error.

Here is the latest one:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [49]:
Line 1:     df['UniqueId'].replace('{',)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py, in __getitem__:
Line 3024:  indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py, in get_loc:
Line 3082:  raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'UniqueId'
```

What must I do?

Comment: there might be whitespace in your column name. try running `df = df.rename(str.strip,axis=1)` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
using regex to search for opening or closing parenthesis, and replacing with null.

```
df['UniqueId'] = df['UniqueId'].replace(r'\{|\}','', regex=True)
```

Comment: still getting KeyError

Comment: @geoJshaun, post your DF then. i just used the key you had in the question. Apparently, it seems in your DF, the key is different. It might have a special character or space in it somewhere.

I tried the solution prior to posting, so it worked for me

Comment: yes it did work and the field name I use is actually an alias, although I renamed columns they're still using same original key value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)

```
df['UniqueId'] = df['UniqueId'].str.strip('{}')
```

Comment: still getting KeyError

Comment: Is your column actually called `UniqueId`? That's the only key involved, so double check that.

Comment: yes, I updated post. Although I renamed columns it appears the UniqueId dield is still assigned to the original key 'doc_id'